# Get selected value (not text) of select list in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm stuck with getting the value attribute of an option in a select list with jQuery Mobile.

My HTML template:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="activity ui-hide-label">
  <label for="activity">Activity</label>
  <select name="activity" id="activity">
    <option value="">Activity</option>
    <option value="3">Athlete</option>
    <option value="2">Regular sports</option>
    <option value="1">No sports</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

My JS function to get the value:

```
function getValue() {
  var activityValue = $('#activity').val();
  console.log("activity value: ", activityValue);
  localStorage['activity'] = activityValue;
}
```

Regardless what I choose from the select list, the variable activityValue is always empty. I also tried with option:selected and similar possibilites.

Obviously the DOM select list doesn't change, when I choose an option. For example, if I choose "Regular sports" the DOM looks like this:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="activity ui-hide-label ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br">
  <label for="activity" class="ui-select">Activity</label>
    <div class="ui-select">
      <div data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="g" data-inline="false" data-mini="false" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-fullsize ui-btn-block ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-up-g">
        <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
          <span class="ui-btn-text">Regular sports</span>
          <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-d ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
        </span>
        <select name="activity" id="activity">
          <option value="">Activity</option>
          <option value="1">Athlete</option>
          <option value="2">Regular sports</option>
          <option value="3">No sports</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm I missing something? To recapitulate: I need the selected value (1,2 or 3) and NOT the text ("Regular sports" in the above example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is an extra function to get the select changes.

```
$('#activity').live( "change", function(event, ui) {
  localStorage['activity'] = $(this).val();
});
```

Thanks to Raminson and thecodeparadox for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

how do you call the `getValue()` function?

try this:

```
$('#activity').change(function(){
    getValue();
})
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to right direction. The change function doesn't work in jQuery Mobile, since the DOM doesn't change. But there is a similar function for jQuery Mobile, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#activity').change(function() { // change event will fire on every selection change
  var activityValue = $(this).val(); // this.value
  console.log("activity value: ", activityValue);
  localStorage['activity'] = activityValue;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to right direction. The change function doesn't work in jQuery Mobile, since the DOM doesn't change. But there is a similar function for jQuery Mobile, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

`var activityValue = $('#activity :selected').val();`